# Интеграция Spring Reactive с Spring MVC + MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, mvc, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

Пытаюсь разобраться, могу ли я использовать *Spring Reactive (Flux/Mono)* вместе с Spring MVC ?
Структура микросервисы с использованием Spring MVC + Feign Client, Eureka Server (Netflix OSS), Hystrix, база данных MySQL.

Мой первый микросервис **addDistanceClient** добавляет данные в базу данных.
Вот пример контроллера:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@RestController
public class RemoteMvcController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService service;

    @GetMapping(path = "/show")
    public List<EmployeeEntity> getAllEmployeesList() {
        return service.getAllEmployees();
    }

}
```

Здесь я могу использовать *Mono/Flux*, я думаю не будет никаких проблем.

Мой второй микросервис **showDistanceClient** - он не связан напрямую с базой данных.
У него есть метод, который вызывает метод (который описан выше) у первого микросервиса для получения данных из базы данных.
Здесь используется Feign Client.

Контроллер второго микросервиса:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class EmployeeMvcController {

    private ServiceFeignClient serviceFeignClient;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/getAllDataFromAddService")
    public String getData2(Model model) {
        List<EmployeeEntity> list = ServiceFeignClient.FeignHolder.create().getAllEmployeesList();
        model.addAttribute("employees", list);
        return "resultlist-employees";
    }

}
```

и сам **ServiceFeignClient**, с помощью которого мы вызываем метод на первом микросервисе, выглядит следующий образом:

```
@FeignClient(name = "add-client", url = "http://localhost:8081/", fallback = Fallback.class)
public interface ServiceFeignClient {

    class FeignHolder {
         public static ServiceFeignClient create() {
            return HystrixFeign.builder().encoder(new GsonEncoder()).decoder(new GsonDecoder()).target(ServiceFeignClient.class, "http://localhost:8081/", new FallbackFactory<ServiceFeignClient>() {
                @Override
                public ServiceFeignClient create(Throwable throwable) {
                    return new ServiceFeignClient() {
                        @Override
                        public List<EmployeeEntity> getAllEmployeesList() {
                            System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @RequestLine("GET /show")
    List<EmployeeEntity> getAllEmployeesList();

}
```

Он работает исправно сейчас. Т.е. если оба микросервиса в порядке, я получаю данные из базы данных.
Если первый микросервис умер, то когда я вызываю метод чтобы получить данные из базы данных через первый микросервис, я получаю страницу, на которой крутится спиннер и текст о том, что сервис недоступен, попробуйте позже. Все отлично.

**Моя цель:**
Сделать так, используя Spring Reactive (не уверен что мне это поможет, но думаю я мыслю в правильном направлении) сделать так, чтобы сообщение что сервис в даный момент недоступен и крутящийся спиннер на втором микросервисе автоматически пропали и отобразились данные из базы данных, как только первый микросервис снова оживет (без повторной отправки запроса, т.е. без перезагрузки страницы).
Смогу ли я это сделать через Spring WebFlux ?
Я знаю что через Spring WebFlux используется поток, который сам нас уведомит, если в нем появятся данные, нам не нужно здесь делать повторную отправку запроса.

Я начал думать над этим и не могу понять, как мне это сделать:

**1)** используя Spring reactive
В таком случае мне надо во втором микросервисе sgowDistanceClient внедрить Flux/Mono в MVC модель, которая возвращает html. Я не понимаю как. Я знаю как это сделать с REST.

**2)** Если первый пункт неверный, может мне надо использовать WebSocket для этого ?
Если это так, поделитесь пожалуйста ползными ссылками с примерами. Буду очень благодарен.

Действительно эта тема мне очень интересна и я хочу разобраться в ней.
Я буду вам очень благодарен за вашу помощь. **Спасибо всем!**

---

**ИЗМЕНЕНО:**

Я переделал оба контроллера под REST + WebFlux. Все работает для меня.

Первый сервис **addDistanceClient** и его контроллер:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BucketController {

    @Autowired
    private BucketRepository bucketRepository;

    // Get all Bucket from the database (every 1 second you will receive 1 record from the DB)
    @GetMapping(value = "/stream/buckets/delay", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Bucket> streamAllBucketsDelay() {
        return bucketRepository.findAll().delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    }

}
```

Он достает из базы данных все записи с интервалом в 5 секунд каждую запись. Интервал я добавил для примера чтобы протестировать.

Второй сервис **showDistanceClient** и его контроллер.
Здесь я использовал ***WebClient*** вместо **Feign Client.**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    @Autowired
    private WebClientService webClientService;

    // Using WebClient
    @GetMapping(value = "/getDataByWebClient",produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Bucket> getDataByWebClient() {
        return webClientService.getDataByWebClient();
    }

}
```

и его Сервис слой (**WebClientService**):

```
@Service
public class WebClientService {

    private static final String API_MIME_TYPE = "application/json";
    private static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8081";
    private static final String USER_AGENT = "User Service";
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebClientService.class);

    private WebClient webClient;

    public WebClientService() {
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, API_MIME_TYPE)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, USER_AGENT)
                .build();
    }

    public Flux<Bucket> getDataByWebClient() {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri("/stream/buckets/delay")
                .exchange()
                .flatMapMany(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToFlux(Bucket.class));
    }

}
```

Теперь все работает в реактивной среде. Отлично.

Но моя проблема осталась нерешенной.

**Моя цель:** все работает, все хорошо, и если вдруг я вызвал на втором сервисе метод который при помощи WebClient вызвал первы сервис чтобы получить данные, и в этот момент мой первый сервис умер, я получил сообщение что сервис временно недоступен и потом мой первый сервис ожил и мой запрос на получение данных продолжилс и я получил все данные и вместо сообщения о том, что сервис временно недоступен я получу все даннык (важно: без перезагрузки страницы).

Как мне добиться этого ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт.
Как оказалось MVC нельзя подружить с WebFlux (точнее можно, но мне нужно возвращать не модель, а реальный json).
Также тот функционал нельзя осуществить: если первый сервис умирает то коннекшен теряется. Невозможно продолжать его держать.
Тут скорее помогут паттерн Retry - но его сложно внедрить в Реактивную среду без свистопляски.
Всем спасибо.